# read variables resolved with `oc.env` as integer in hydra

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

In my project, I'm setting an environment variables using python-dotenv.
I then reference it in my YAML using the `co.env` OmegaConf resolver.

```yaml
# config.yaml
var1: 42
var2: ${oc.env:PROJECT_NUMBER}
```

```
# .env
PROJECT_NUMBER=99
```

Once I run my script, however, the variable appears to be always parsed as a string:

```py
# content of config 
{'var1': 42, 'var2': '99'}
```

As far as I understand from [here](https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/issues/573), this is the intended behavior of `oc.env`, and the `env` resolver which would guess the primitive type is being deprecated.
How do I ensure that `var2` is read as an integer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [oc.decode](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html#oc-decode) to decode to get it as a number.

Something like:

```yaml
var1: 42
var2: ${oc.decode:${oc.env:PROJECT_NUMBER}}
```